# What is a word for a man who has a lot of sexual relationships?

Tags: word-choice, vocabulary, epithet-requests

What do you call a man who loves and tries to have many sexual relationships with girls and usually doesn't fall in love with any of them?

To clear what I'm looking for, Suppose a guy at work/university who tries to have sexual relationship with many girls and changes his choice continually one after another!

Comment: I think the word I would use depends on whether he was successful or not and also whether you mean "girls" as *girls* or slang for *young (adult) women*.

Comment: The word is "teenage boy"

Comment: I believe it's "Tiger"

Comment: Is it a slang you are looking for?

Comment: @Kit: Never thought about my question that specific! I meant adult women. Your suggestion for both cases is welcomed.

@Kirk Hammett: I like to hear some slang too.

Comment: “Wants to get in all the girls’ pants” would do it

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I suggest **Lothario** defined by [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lothario) defined by  as *an unscrupulous seducer of women*.

It's from the name of such a character in Nicholas Rowe's 1703 tragedy [The Fair Penitent](http://www.enotes.com/oce-encyclopedia/fair-penitent)

dictionary.com adds the definitions [rake, libertine](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/lothario) and synonyms *Romeo, Don Juan, Casanova*.

The *Office Romeo* is a well-worn term, but I don't often hear *Romeo* on its own.

To my ear, *Don Juan* and *Casanova* have become rather quaint 'literary' clichés much overused by the mass-media, but somehow *Lothario* still seems to have a certain freshness. Maybe using it gives the impression you're well-read, rather than getting all your words from popular tv dramas.

Answer (score 16):

It is often referred to as a [Casanova](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giacomo_Casanova) after the Venetian **womaniser**.

Also related, but actually *predating* the real person Giacomo Casanova is the fictional character *[Don Juan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don_Juan)* who has inspired among other masterpieces the Opera "Don Giovanni" by Mozart and the play "[Dom Juan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dom_Juan)" by Molière.

Wikipedia pleasantly notes that Giacomo Casanova probably attended the première of Mozart's opera in Prague.

Comment: Also **Don Juan** from the same source

Comment: Thanks Martin. May I add this to the answer ?

Comment: @That's the idea of SE! I would say Don Juan is a slightly old fashioned phrase

Comment: I think Don Juan *and* Casanova are both pretty old fashioned, but both would probably be readily understood by a native speaker.

Comment: @Kit: I agree.  I think [man-whore](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/26840/a-word-for-a-man-who-has-a-lot-of-sexual-relationships/26843#26843) would be a more contemporary answer.

Comment: what about "womanizer" / "womaniser" itself?

Comment: @Kit: Depends on where you're from. *Don Juan* may be old-fashioned, but *Casanova* certainly isn't. You could also shorten *Don Juan* to *DJ* to sound more hip ;)

Answer (score 15):

Promiscuous - not being restricted to just one sexual partner.  It is gender-neutral, so you'll still have to specify the sex of the subject.

Comment: isn't it an adjective?

Answer (score 11):

philanderer - To engage in many love affairs, especially with a frivolous or casual attitude. Used of a man.

Comment: Philanderer is usually used for a married man who is cheating on his wife, I think.

Comment: @Kit: Not really. Though a large part of its usage may address married men, the word itself carries no connotation of marital status.

Answer (score 9):

***Satyromaniac*** [sey-tuh-roh-mey-nee-ak]:

> a lascivious man; lecher

It derives from Greek (sátyro) for the mythical woodland creature that was well-known for its debauchery.  The female equivalent is far more recognizable, *nymphomaniac*.

Comment: +1 because it has more syllables than you could shake a stick at.

Comment: Nymphomaniac is actually truly feminine and satyromaniac is the masculine?

Comment: Honestly, I think I'd go with lecher before satyromaniac...If only to avoid the "big word" look.-_-

Comment: +1 for the correctness of the answer and the fast that I will never say it out loud, not because I don't know any, but for fear of pronouncing it incorrectly.

Answer (score 8):

I believe common usage for such a person is a "man-whore". I'd call him a narcissist or a creep or some other such term.

Comment: @music2myear: *man-whore* is fairly non-standard slang, and a *narcissist* is obsessed with himself rather than women. And while *creep* (even when correctly spelt) was particularly used with that specific meaning 60-70 years ago, today it's used for just about any undesirable person hanging around a group.

Comment: I would say sleeping with a lot of people without regard for them could be a symptom of narcissism, the self love trumping regard for others. I wouldn't necessarily call a man-whore a narcissist.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I would say that *man-whore* is actually [fairly common](http://www.google.com/search?q=man-whore) slang, at least in the US.  When I read the title of this question, *man-whore* was the first thing that popped into my mind, so +1!

Comment: @josh3736: Perhaps it's a generational thing. If we were talking about a young unattached guy, I'd just call him **normal**. If he was older, but was still living like that, I'd want to be more circumspect. After all, if we were in an office, presumably at any given time he'd either be shagging one of the women there, or trying to get into her pants. Maybe the boss's, and that could be seriously disruptive. So I'd just put it about that he was a bit of a Lothario and let people make up their own minds.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I agree with josh3736 that "man-whore" is common slang in the under 35 crowd.  I'm not sure that it's the best term here though.

Comment: @Kit: What about gays, are they still *man-whores*?

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes, they are still *man-whores*.

Comment: In my (admittedly not at all "in" set) we simply used *"slut"* for both genders when it seemed appropriate. As in *"In Star Trek TOS the Captain was the slut, but in TNG it was the XO."*

Comment: @dmckee: Absolutely. Except I think gender-neutral "*slut*" is mostly used by and of under-30's, but the older generation only use it for women. And middle-aged people just don't talk about that kind of thing much anyway. Too old to bandy it around in idle banter, too young to get morally indignant enough to use it in earnest.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Usage of *man-whore* is most definitely a generational thing -- anecdotally, usage is common among my peers (20s), but very uncommon among older people.  However, I'd disagree with calling a young, unattached guy who engages in a lot of flings as **normal**: the [median number of *lifetime* sexual partners for an adult male is seven](http://www.msnbc.msn.com/id/19374216/).  A guy in university who runs through 7 partners in a semester would qualify as a man-whore; but research tells us those types are more of an exception (<29%), not 'normal.'

Comment: @josh3736: To be honest, by the time that guy in uni was on his 4th or 5th partner in a single term, I'd be more concerned about the standards of the next woman in line. I'd also say that *any* behaviour pattern applicable to 25-30% of the population qualifies as 'normal' in my book, whether I endorse it or not.

Answer (score 6):

I'm sure my slang will date me, but the first word I thought of was *[player](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=player)* (Urban Dictionary): a man who has sexual relations with lots of women, usually by deceiving them into thinking that he truly cares.  If he's good at it, he'd be a *[mackdaddy](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=mackdaddy)* (Urban Dictionary).  If he's bad at it, he'd be a *[sleaze](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=sleaze)* (Urban Dictionary) or a *[pervert](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pervert)* (Dictionary.com)

Also, as mentioned in the other answers, *man-whore* and *male slut* or just *slut* would also be suitable.  These three imply promiscuity, but with less deception, I think.

*Womanizer* or *philanderer* are good non-slang versions of the same, as are the various names of iconic womanizers that were mentioned in other answers.

Answer (score 3):

I've heard "swordsman" used in that respect, usually in a somewhat sarcastic tone.  For instance, "He thinks he's quite the swordsman".

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest an apposite word is [cocksman](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cocksman).

Answer (score 2):

I knew a guy just like you described and he got a nickname "Male [Tart](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=tart)"

Comment: I often hear just *tart* used by the younger generation for male & female. Sometimes maybe a bit facetiously when refering to a male, but certainly not always. For my generation I think it's like *slut*. We just don't tend to use *any* such words much at all.

Comment: I've heard "slut" referring to man a number of times- but never once referring to a woman.