# "Sl*t" term for males

Tags: single-word-requests, offensive-language

"Slut" can have two meanings:

- an immoral woman, or prostitute
- a dirty and slovenly woman

I would like a term for men that is the equivalent of the second meaning. Is there a term for describing a man that is dirty and slovenly?

Comment: [A word for a man who has a lot of sexual relationships](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/26840/2851)

Comment: N.B. some speakers use "slut" to refer to men, although usually with the first sense, I think.

Comment: @Neil Coffey:  I've only ever heard of this being used toward cross-dressing males.  What was the topic/context from those speakers?

Comment: The second use of slut is definitely now archaic. In effect, there isn't an equivalent, because that use of slut itself is no longer in use.

Comment: @Marcin:  In that light (but not a _night light_), what's your perspective on other similar terms like "gigolo?"

Comment: Randolf -- it's commonly used among (male?) gay speakers to refer to other males who sleep around. Cross-dressing isn't obligatory as far as I'm aware.

Comment: @Randolf: As far as I know, it only refers to a male sex worker, not an unkempt man.

Comment: Thanks @Neil Coffey and @Marcin.  It's really amazing how these subtle points can be so easily forgotten when words become popular.

Comment: @Marcin-- I think it's more to a person who sleeps around for pleasure than because they're a sex worker! (Whereas "tart", at least when referring to females, can have both connotations.)

Comment: Anecdotal: I and many of my friends use 'slut' to refer to promiscuous straight men.

Comment: @dmckee (and everyone else in this comment chain) - That wasn't the question. Pretend you didn't read the title, and read the last sentence in the question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"Slob" captures the second meaning for either sex.
Are you looking for a term that would be used only for men?

Comment: "Slut" has a sexual connotation where "slob" does not.  Also, where a slut may be visually attractive (especially in the context of being a prostitute), the image of a "slob" is usually a visually unattractive one.

Comment: @Randolf Richardson, Remember the question is asking for a word equivalent to the second meaning. IT doesn't have to relate to the first meaning. Monica Cellio's word is excellent

Comment: @Third Idiot:  Ah, yes, you're right (+1 for you).  The title of this article put a lot of weight on that for me.

Comment: Interesting how all the men who answered completely missed the question once the thought of it being about sex entered their heads. :-)

Comment: @T.E.D.:  That's because "slut" has an _overpowering_ sexual connotation.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know why @Monica says "slob" applies to both sexes. I often hear (particularly younger) people apply "slut" (and "slag") to males, but I rarely hear "slob" applied to females. This NGram chart seems to confirm my somewhat sexist distinction...

[image]

...in that what I see as "wrong gender" usages don't even show up at all.

Comment: Harry Enfield's Television Programme in the 1990s had a sketch about a man and women called [The Slobs](http://www.bbc.co.uk/comedy/clips/p0089856/harry_enfields_television_programme_the_slobs/) who were both slobs.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest "gigolo" as a term that is probably quite suitable since it specifically refers to the male sex.  Although it may not be quite as low-class or *dirty* as "slut," it's probably close enough to meet most needs.

Comment: "gigolo" has a positive connotation (a bit like "man-eater"), though, whereas "slut" has a negative connotation.

Comment: @Neil Coffey, Gigolo  used to refer to male prostitutes..

Comment: It still does, but in a positive way.

Answer (score -1):

As @Joe said, the meaning with sexual connotations could be "dog".

The meaning of slovenly, "pig".

Answer (score -2):

True, you can use whatever word that most fits your mood. It's strange to me to call a man a slut. It sounds like

> Greg didn't say a thing, because he was busy in the middle of
>   delegations while my professors got mad at me and called me a slut.