# "Straight man" is to "womanizer" as gay man is to _______

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm trying to find a word for a gay man, regardless of gender presentation, who tries to seduce lots of guys. Could be pejorative or favorable. Promiscuous and philanderer could work but they're not specific to gay men.

Example: Andrew was such a _____ that he even flirted with guys he knew were straight.

Related:

["Man" is to "womanizer" as "woman" is to what?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/69129/man-is-to-womanizer-as-woman-is-to-what)

[What is a word for a man who has a lot of sexual relationships?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/26840/what-is-a-word-for-a-man-who-has-a-lot-of-sexual-relationships)

Answer (score -1):

Honestly, I think "man-whore" may be used. Self-explanatory, though may not be politically correct.

Answer (score -1):

It's vulgar and probably more 'internet slang', and I do like "man-whore", but I'd say *fuckboy* (or *fuckboi*) is more akin to *womanizer*, as most millennials consider *fuckboy* to be less gender specific (and more modern term), as well as inclusive of sexuality, than *womanizer*.

Comment: Can you provide any reference to establish that this word is in use, and what it means? I’m not familiar with it; it seems like something that could apply to a heterosexual man.